# Why is my implementation of linear regression not working?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement linear regression from scratch in python.

For reference, here are the mathematical formulae I have used: [Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zzc1.png)

This is what I tried:

```py
class LinearRegression:
    
    def __init__(
    self, 
    features: np.ndarray[np.float64],
    targets: np.ndarray[np.float64],
    ) -> None:
        self.features = np.concatenate((np.ones((features.shape[0], 1)), features), axis=1)
        self.targets = targets
        self.params = np.random.randn(features.shape[1] + 1)
        self.num_samples = features.shape[0]
        self.num_feats = features.shape[1]
        self.costs = []
    
    def hypothesis(self) -> np.ndarray[np.float64]:
        return np.dot(self.features, self.params)
    
    def cost_function(self) -> np.float64:
        pred_vals = self.hypothesis()
        return (1 / (2 * self.num_samples)) * np.dot((pred_vals - self.targets).T, pred_vals - self.targets)
    
    def update(self, alpha: np.float64) -> None:
        self.params = self.params - (alpha / self.num_samples) * (self.features.T @ (self.hypothesis() - self.targets))
    
    def gradientDescent(self, alpha: np.float64, threshold: np.float64, max_iter: int) -> None:
        converged = False
        counter = 0
        while not converged:
            counter += 1
            curr_cost = self.cost_function()
            self.costs.append(curr_cost)
            self.update(alpha)
            new_cost = self.cost_function()
            if abs(new_cost - curr_cost) < threshold:
                converged = True
            if counter > max_iter:
                converged = True
```

I used the class like this:

```py
regr = LinearRegression(features=np.linspace(0, 1000, 200, dtype=np.float64).reshape((20, 10)), targets=np.linspace(0, 200, 20, dtype=np.float64))
regr.gradientDescent(0.1, 1e-3, 1e+3)
regr.cost_function()
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar power
  return (1 / (2 * self.num_samples)) * (la.norm(self.hypothesis() - self.targets) ** 4)

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar subtract
  if abs(new_cost - curr_cost) < threshold:

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in matmul
  self.params = self.params - (alpha / self.num_samples) * (self.features.T @ (self.hypothesis() - self.targets))
```

What is going wrong exactly?

Comment: Hey, I've haven't looked into what's wrong yet but I want to mention that you don't need gradient descent for linear regression. There's a closed form solution to find the optimal weights. It's the Moore-Penrose inverse of the input X times the expected output Y. You can find more about it when you google it. Thus, if the error is somewhere in the GD part, you can get rid of that by not using GD.

Comment: I am aware of the closed form solution particularly the Normal equations but asymptotically, calculating the closed form solution takes O(n ^ 3) time since we have to take the transpose of a matrix. I think gradient descent would perform better but I digress. This implementation of gradient descent is quite simple and should work. But I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Why do you have the power of 4 in the cost function? Should be 2.

Comment: I was originally using the L2 norm which gave the sum of squares of elements of a vector under a square root so I had to take the power of 4. But I have modified the cost function according to the more standard formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is overflowing because you use to large numbers in your example. Try using:

```
regr = LinearRegression(features=np.linspace(0, 1000, 200, dtype=np.float64).reshape((20, 10))/1000, targets=np.linspace(0, 200, 20, dtype=np.float64)/1000)
regr.gradientDescent(0.1, 1e-3, 1e+3)
regr.cost_function()
```

It gives me an output of 0.00474225348416323.